# Is possible delete textnodes of undesired tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tested Jsoup and I can't delete the textnodes of undesired tags.
Idk if I wrong methods.
The method is:

```
String pretty = Jsoup.clean("<img src=\"marco\">Capretta</img><i>Sono misterioso</i><p color=\"white\"><font size=\"5\">Ciao</p><p>some text</p><br/> <p>another text</p></font>" , "", Whitelist.basic().addTags("br", "p","i"), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(true));
System.out.println(pretty);
```

The result is:

```
Capretta
<i>Sono misterioso</i>
<p>Ciao</p>
<p>some text</p>
<br> 
<p>another text</p>
```

But I not want the textnodes of `<img>` ( is valid also for other undesired tags) ...

So the result is better so:

```
<i>Sono misterioso</i>
<p>Ciao</p>
<p>some text</p>
<br> 
<p>another text</p>
```

I can have also different html...

P.s. The question is for Java and not Javascript!!!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your HTML is simple enough.

you can achieve this by `parsing` the `HTML` first then retrieve the `children of body tag`

```
String pretty = Jsoup.clean("<img src=\"marco\">Capretta</img><i>Sono misterioso</i><p color=\"white\"><font size=\"5\">Ciao</p><p>some text</p><br/> <p>another text</p></font>" , "", Whitelist.basic().addTags("br", "p","i"), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(true));
pretty= Jsoup.parse(pretty).getElementsByTag("body").get(0).children().toString();
System.out.println(pretty);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<i>Sono misterioso</i>
<p>Ciao</p>
<p>some text</p>
<br />
<p>another text</p>
```

Comment: Yeas assuning but I can have different html so it not work.

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani yeah, I'm sure u have a reason for it. but I never had a  need to clean em up.

Comment: There is always a first time, well seems that last cache is the "oldest" regex.
But I wait other user for give a good response

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is this: The `<img>` html tag does not allow any text nodes within, i.e. it does not have closing tag. The `</img>` you have in your example is not valid html. An image can't span over inner text like that. See [here for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img)

So JSoup ignores the closing `</img>`, since it is not valid.

A way out would be to use the XML parser of Jsoup:

```
String html = "<img src=\"marco\">Capretta</img><i>Sono misterioso</i>"
            + "<p color=\"white\"><font size=\"5\">Ciao</p>"
            + "<p>some text</p><br/> <p>another text</p></font>";
Document xmldoc = Jsoup.parse(html, "",Parser.xmlParser());
Elements imgs = xmldoc.select("img");
imgs.remove();

System.out.println(xmldoc);
```

Comment: Agree... yeah you mean correct that '<img>'  contain an inner text! like textnode.
this code work too